# How to install Java in Rocker/Shiny container in Ubuntu

Tags: java, docker, shiny, dockerfile, shiny-server

I am currently testing Rocker/Shiny container for my project. There are some libraries that require "rJava" as its dependencies but when I tried to install "rJava", it had an error caused by the rocker/shiny container that doesn't have Java coming with it. So, I have tried

```
# Install Java.
echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections && \
add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer
```

with some modification to install java but wasn't successful. it stopped at

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
```

and complained

```
No such file or directory: 'gpg'
```

I also tried to copy jdk-*-*.tar.gz to the container as well but no luck either.

So, I would like to know how I can install java in the rocker/container in order for me to successfully install rJava.

Any helps will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend `rocker/shiny` image by adding Java on top of it. Then you'll be able to run a docker container using your new image.

Create a `Dockerfile` with the following code:

```
FROM rocker/shiny:latest

# install wget and gnupg
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -my wget gnupg

# install oracle java 8
RUN echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections \
    && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list \
    && echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list \
    && apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886 \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install oracle-java8-installer -y

# clean local repository
RUN apt-get clean

# set up JAVA_HOME
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Build it using:

```
docker build -t rocker_with_java .
```

You can verify your java installation by running:

```
docker run -it rocker_with_java java -version
```